# Show in HTML the Options Value which is the output of the code from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**EDITED:**

I have coded in *JavaScript* to call a function on *Google Apps Script* which will check my data in google sheet and get the values needed.

code for JavaScript:

```
   function setTime(){
   var lookDate = document.getElementById("subDate").value;
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dateOk).timeCheck(lookDate);
   }
   
   function dateOk(dateData){
   document.getElementById("subTime").innerHTML = dateData;
   console.log(dateData);
   }
```

Sample scenario for this, When a user select a `Date` in my Web App, it will run the `function setTime()` and then it will go to the Google Apps Script code. I have two functions `function timeCheck(lookDate)` and `function testRow(dataDisable,lookDate)`. Function `timeCheck(lookDate)` will check my values in my Google Sheet and will look for the limits, and function `testRow(dataDisable,lookDate)` will look for the limit values and change the values in its corresponding column in my Google Sheet.

for Google Apps Script:

```
function timeCheck(lookDate){
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");  
  var myData = ws.getRange(2, 7, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();
  var arrData = [];
  myData.forEach(function(row){
    
  var lookup = lookDate;
  var dte = new Date (row[0]);
  var form = Utilities.formatDate(dte, 'GMT+8', 'MMM dd, yyyy');

    if(form == lookup){
      arrData.push(row[1]); 
    }    
  });
  var myVals = arrData;
  var CheckLimitReached = function (V) {
    var records= {};
    V.forEach(function (x) { records[x] = (records[x] || 0) + 1; });
    var limit_reached = Object.keys(records).filter(function (R) {
      return records[R] >= 3;});
    return limit_reached;
    
  };
   var dataDisable = CheckLimitReached(myVals);
  //testRow(dataDisable,lookDate);
  var list1= testRow(dataDisable,lookDate)
  return list1 
}



function testRow(dataDisable,lookDate){

       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url); 
  var ts = ss.getSheetByName("Time_Select");
  var checkData = ts.getRange(1, 1, 1, ts.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];

  var index = checkData.indexOf(lookDate)+1;
  var x = [];
  var dateValues = ts.getRange(2, index, ts.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  //var checkSplit = dateValues.map(function(row){return row[0]; });
  for(var i=0;i<dataDisable.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<dateValues.length;j++){
      if(dataDisable[i]==dateValues[j][0]){
        dateValues[j][0]="Not Available"
      }
    }
  }
  ts.getRange(2, index, ts.getLastRow()-1, 1).setValues(dateValues);
  var listVal = ts.getRange(2, index, ts.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var list1 = listVal.getValues();//.toString();
  return list1;
}
```

The log result of this function is:

```
[19-09-10 13:36:58:034 HKT] [[Not Available], [Not Available], [10:00 AM], [11:00 AM], [12:00 NN], [1:00 PM], [Not Available], [3:00 PM]
```

My problem is how to reflect the values in my html as options.

Here is the link of my Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lEfzjG1zzJVPMN8r-OpeZm6q9_IqSwk9DNCEY-q7ozY/edit?usp=sharing

and here is my html code for the web app:

```
<!-- DATE SELECTION -->
       <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s4">
             <input id="subDate" type="text" class="datepicker">
             <label for="subDate">Select Date</label>
          </div> <!-- CLOSE TIME FIELD -->
       
 <!-- TIME SELECTION -->      
          <div class="input-field col s4">
             <select id="subTime">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your preferred time</option>                  
              <?!= list1; ?>
             </select>
             <label>Select Time</label>
          </div> <!-- CLOSE TIME FIELD -->
       </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
```

Thank you in advance for your answers and inputs.

***EDIT/ UPDATE:***

I've tried this code in JavaScript to remove the existing options and add the values as new options in HMTL. Unfortunately nothing happened.

JavaScript:

```
function dateOk(dateData){
console.log(dateData)
var selectRemove = document.getElementById("subTime");
selectRemove.innerHTML = "";
           
for (var option in dateData){
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.innerHTML = option;
selectRemove.options.add(newOption);
}
```

***Problem:*** How to remove the existing Select Options and replace it with the return values from the function? Or How to create a dropdown list box with the values reflected?

Comment: @TheMaster I think my explanation was not sufficient. Thank you for the reply. I just need to reflect the output value in the sample log above to html as options. I tried using the `innerHtml` command but unfortunately the return value in the javascript is `undefined`

Comment: @TheMaster My question was also not a duplicate of Send mail, since my concern is how to reflect my values in html. Anyway, thank you for the answers, I'm still searching for ways. :)

Comment: @TheMaster So you mean even if its running and getting my desired output, it is still invalid since my dates are objects? Thank you for the enlightenment. :)

Comment: `innerHtml` should be [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) uppercase

Comment: @TheMaster just a question, will converting the `list1` values to string and returning it to the javaScript code be fine or do you suggest to do something more? I tried to convert the `list1` values to string and run it using the `doGet()` function but it does not display the values in the option. Thank you so much

Comment: TBH, your question is confusing. 1. Did you try changing to uppercase innerHTML? 2. What is your problem? Does `doGet()` not work? Or ``dateOk()`` not work ? Can you [edit] your question to explain the logic flow with works or not works attached to each step? 3. Which variable are you logging and where which becomes `undefined`? 4.What type values are you sending from client? `typeof input`? Is it a date object?

Comment: @TheMaster My apologies for the confusion. I tried changing to uppercase innerHTML but the fucntion `dateOk ()` still returns `undefined`. My problem is I cannot display the result of my `testRow()` as select option in my html. I will edit my question, thank you for the advice and again I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: You aren't ``return``ing `list1` from `testRow` and  you aren't `return`ing `testRow` return value from `timeCheck` and thus `dateData` in `dateOk` is ``undefined``

Comment: @TheMaster I combined the `timeCheck()` function and the `testRow()` function and return a value which results to what I need: `<option>Not Available</option><option>Not Available</option><option>10:00 AM</option><option>11:00 AM</option><option>12:00 NN</option><option>1:00 PM</option><option>Not Available</option><option>3:00 PM</option>` but the innerHTML was not working. I'm still looking for solutions. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Could you point out the `return` statement in each function? You're logging it but not `return`ing it. Remove `doGet` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

- No return value provided for any function called.
- `innetHtml` should be `innerHTML`

#### Snippet:

```
function testRow(dataDisable,lookDate){
  /*...rest of code*/
  var list1 = listVal.getValues();
  Logger.log(list1);
  return list1;//ADDED: returns to `timecheck`
  //REMOVEDdoGet(list1); 
}
```

```
function timeCheck(lookDate){
  /*...rest of code*/
  var dataDisable = CheckLimitReached(myVals);
  return testRow(dataDisable,lookDate);//MODIFIED return the value of function `testRow` from `timeCheck` to `dateOk`
}
```

```
function dateOk(dateData){
 console.log(dateData);
 document.getElementById("subTime").innerHTML = dateData.reduce((a,c)=>{
    return a+'<option>' + (c[0] === 'Not Available' ? '' : c[0]) + '</option>'
 },'');
}
```

#### To Read and practice:

- [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

#### Live Snippet:

```html
<div class="input-field col s4">
<select id="subTime">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your preferred time</option>                  
 
</select>
<label>Select Time</label>
 </div> <!-- CLOSE TIME FIELD -->
<script>
function dateOk(dateData){
 console.log(dateData);
 document.getElementById("subTime").innerHTML = dateData.reduce((a,c)=>{
return a+'<option>' + (c[0] === 'Not Available' ? '' : c[0]) + '</option>'
 },'');
}
dateOk([["Not Available"], ["10:00AM"], ["5:00PM"]]);//call function as if called from successHandler
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the replies. I tried your suggestions and I got this output using the console log `(8) […]
​
0: Array [ "Not Available" ]
​
1: Array [ "Not Available" ]
​
2: Array [ "10:00 AM" ]
​
3: Array [ "11:00 AM" ]
​
4: Array [ "12:00 NN" ]
​
5: Array [ "1:00 PM" ]
​
6: Array [ "Not Available" ]
​
7: Array [ "3:00 PM" ]
​
length: 8
​
<prototype>: Array []` unfortunately, I still cannot reflect or display the output as select option event though I used the `document.getElementById("subTime").innerHTML = dateData;`

Comment: @Glenn You should be able to fix that on your own. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm searching for answers. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your edited code still does not reflect the output on the html even though we're using innerHTML. Still looking for solution. Thank you so much,

Comment: I've edited the javascript code as stated above, unfortunately nothing happened.

Comment: @Glenn Added a live snippet: you can click "Run code snippet" to see that it's working.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried your live snippet in my javaScript. But still the one reflected was the one in my HTML and not the result. I've tried many options but still not working. I even tried the `var select = document.createElement('select');
       
       for (index in timeData){
       var opt = document.createElement('option');
       opt.value = index;
       opt.innerHTML = timeData[index];
       
       select.appendChild(opt);
       }
       
       document.getElementById("subTime").appendChild(select)` but still unsucessful. :( Thank you

Comment: @Glenn Why do you think it's not working? Any error on the console? Try disabling all other scripts/css/frameworks and use plain html.

Comment: I think I found the problem. It's the initialization of the `select` because of using MaterializeCSS. Your code is working. Thank you very much.